# Generate github docs within the branch (not gh-pages)

Tags: git, github, documentation

I am trying to use sphinx to generate docs to my package. Naturally, I started with the simpler case and followed the [default tutorial](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-project-pages-manually/), which worked fine. However, every [other tutorial that I found](https://daler.github.io/sphinxdoc-test/includeme.html) follows this path: make a fresh close, create a `gh-pages` branch, remove the rest and push.

I really don't understand how the logistics would work this way, though. Ideally, I'd like to have one `docs` for every branch, just like [this example](https://github.com/hgrecco/pint/tree/master/docs), which produces [this page](https://pint.readthedocs.io/en/0.7.2/). But I found no tutorial that teaches how to do that.

This way (having one docs for every branch) I can document my changes to each branch within the branch's docs and them merge them (docs and code) into the master naturally. This would also make handling of versions/releases much easier.

By having one separate branch that has the docs I really can't visualize how to work the changes and specially the releases, since ideally you'd have one version of the docs for every release. (When I add a label to the master do I have to manually switch to `gh-pages`, document the changes and create a similar label there? I'm really lost here.)

To sum up:

How do I have one `docs` for each branch (like [my example](https://github.com/hgrecco/pint/tree/master/docs)).

And how do I manage branches and releases in the docs?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I finally did it was creating a worktree within my main dir. Since I planned on using sphinx, I created a workdir in `repo/docs/_build/html` following [this tutorial](http://blog.jenkster.com/2016/02/git-for-static-sites.html).

Basically, after you create an orphan `gh-pages` the command is

```
git worktree add docs/_build/html gh-pages
```

assuming you are in `.git/..`. That way you can setup sphinx in docs and it will build the html already into the html directory, which is the `gh-pages` branch.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a README file contains your documentation and commit it to every branch you have.

Since it will be a different file per branch you will be bale to manage it per branch with a different content.

If you use git hub you can also use templates to do so.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I follow. How is it that a README file will contain the whole documentation? (the docs are big)